# random oversampling for multiple categories in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, text, data-mining

I'm trying to do random sampling method on a unbalanced dataset to predict the appropriate 'category' for the given 'description'.

```
df_1['Category'].value_counts().loc[lambda x : x>1]
```

The categories are too many and uneven. I want to bring them all to an equal level so the machine learning model will not predict always let say 'iam~ki-000' as they are too many.

```
 iam~ki-000                378
 iam~ki-002                180
 iam~ki-049                 99
 iam~ki-050                 91
 iam~ki-057                 91
                          ... 
 iam~ki-077                  2
```

So far I can come up with only one solution and that is very ineffective:(

That is to do an individual calculation to multiply each category to oversample the dataset. There are almost 90 categories in total. Can someone help me out to write a function that aggregates all categories evenly?

```
ki-057 = dataframe['Category'] == iam~ki-000
df_try = df[ki-057]
df = df.append([df_try]*4,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373088/duplicating-training-examples-to-handle-class-imbalance-in-a-pandas-data-frame

Comment: @isydmr Thank you this might work. I will update the code after testing.

Comment: checkout `RandomOverSampler` class from `imblearn`. This is where I am getting this info from: https://machinelearningmastery.com/random-oversampling-and-undersampling-for-imbalanced-classification/