# Over and under sample multi-class training examples (rows) in a pandas dataframe to specified values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, oversampling

I would like to make a multi-class pandas dataframe more balanced for training. A simplified version of my training set looks as follows:

**Imbalanced dataframe: counts for class 0, 1 and 2 are respectively 7, 3 and 1**

```
   animal  class
0    dog1      0
1    dog2      0
2    dog3      0
3    dog4      0
4    dog5      0
5    dog6      0
6    dog7      0
7    cat1      1
8    cat2      1
9    cat3      1
10  fish1      2
```

I made this with the code:

```
import pandas as pd    
data = {'animal': ['dog1', 'dog2', 'dog3', 'dog4','dog5', 'dog6', 'dog7', 'cat1','cat2', 'cat3', 'fish1'], 'class': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2]}   
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now I would like to randomly under sample the majority class(es) and randomly over sample the minority class(es) to specified values per class to get a more balanced dataframe.

The problem is that all pandas tutorials I can find online or other questions on stackoverflow on this topic deal with either random over sampling the minority class to the level of the majority class (eg: [Duplicating training examples to handle class imbalance in a pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373088/duplicating-training-examples-to-handle-class-imbalance-in-a-pandas-data-frame?fbclid=IwAR3xV2OJsA_JWOZranmPiD2KQOMQW9gb4t30XMCMdh99U2PP5139sHzLIZs))  or random under sampling the majority class to the level of the minority class.

Since I face extreme imbalance, I cannot make the size of the majority classes equal to that of the minority class. Therefore, these code snippets I can find typically don't work for me. Ideally, I would be able to specify the exact number of samples per class that are then generated by either over- or under sampling (depending on the number I specified for that class and the number of samples the class contains).

For example,

if I specify:

- counts_0 = 5 (was 7 so implies random **under** sampling with 2 samples),
- counts_1 = 4 (was 3 so implies random **over** sampling with 1 sample),
- counts_2 = 3 (was 1 implies random **over** sampling with 2 samples)

I would like to become something like this:

**More balanced dataframe: counts for class 0, 1 and 2 are respectively 5, 4 and 3**

```
   animal  class
0    dog2      0
1    dog3      0
2    dog5      0
3    dog6      0
4    dog7      0
5    cat1      1
6    cat2      1
7    cat3      1
8    cat2      1
9   fish1      2
10  fish1      2
11  fish1      2
```

What would be the best approach to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`groupby.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html) does not allow `n` to be larger than the group size if `replace` is not `True` but having replace be `True` means that replacement will occur even in groups that could have been downsampled.

Instead let's try with [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) + [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) and conditionally enable `replace` per group.
Create a dictionary that maps each class to number of samples, and use the conditional logic to determine with or without replacement:

```
sample_amounts = {0: 5, 1: 4, 2: 3}

s = (
    df.groupby('class').apply(lambda g: g.sample(
        # lookup number of samples to take
        n=sample_amounts[g.name],
        # enable replacement if len is less than number of samples expected
        replace=len(g) < sample_amounts[g.name]  
    ))
)
```

`s`:

```
         animal  class
class                 
0     5    dog6      0
      3    dog4      0
      6    dog7      0
      4    dog5      0
      2    dog3      0
1     9    cat3      1
      8    cat2      1
      7    cat1      1
      8    cat2      1
2     10  fish1      2
      10  fish1      2
      10  fish1      2
```

---

[`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) can be used to keep the initial index (if important):

```
sample_amounts = {0: 5, 1: 4, 2: 3}

s = (
    df.groupby('class').apply(lambda g: g.sample(
        n=sample_amounts[g.name],
        replace=len(g) < sample_amounts[g.name]
    ))
    .droplevel(0)
)
```

`s`:

```
   animal  class
6    dog7      0
3    dog4      0
2    dog3      0
4    dog5      0
1    dog2      0
7    cat1      1
8    cat2      1
8    cat2      1
8    cat2      1
10  fish1      2
10  fish1      2
10  fish1      2
```

[`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas-dataframe-reset-index) can be used if the index is not important:

```
sample_amounts = {0: 5, 1: 4, 2: 3}

s = (
    df.groupby('class').apply(lambda g: g.sample(
        n=sample_amounts[g.name],
        replace=len(g) < sample_amounts[g.name]
    ))
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

`s`:

```
   animal  class
0    dog1      0
1    dog2      0
2    dog4      0
3    dog5      0
4    dog3      0
5    cat3      1
6    cat2      1
7    cat1      1
8    cat3      1
9   fish1      2
10  fish1      2
11  fish1      2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way of over and undersampling in 1 line when you want all classes to have the same amount per class:

```
no_sample = 5
balanced_df=df.groupby(
    "class",
    as_index=False,
    group_keys=False
  ).apply(
    lambda s: s.sample(no_sample,replace=True)
)


print(balanced_df)


   animal  class
1    dog2      0
6    dog7      0
4    dog5      0
6    dog7      0
0    dog1      0
7    cat1      1
8    cat2      1
7    cat1      1
9    cat3      1
8    cat2      1
10  fish1      2
10  fish1      2
10  fish1      2
10  fish1      2
10  fish1      2
```